# getMock - multiple instances of the same class

Tags: php, phpunit

If I have a class A that interacts with class B then in my tests I want to mock class B so that I can test class A in isolation.

This is easy to do in PHPUnit with `"getMock('classname')"`.

My problem currently is: If `class A` uses multiple instances of `class B` I can't simulate this with `"getMock('B')"` because it appears that `"getMock"` will not return multiple instances if called multiple times but always the same mock of `class B`.

**Following Example:**

```
<?php

class A()
{
    private class_b_1;
    private class_b_2;


    public function setClassB1(B $class_b)
    {
        $this->class_b_1 = $class_b;
    }

    public function setClassB2(B $class_b)
    {
        $this->class_b_2 = $class_b;
    }   
}
```

And in my tests:

```
$mock_one_of_class_b = $this -> getMock('B');
$mock_two_of_class_b = $this -> getMock('B');
```

Then `$mock_one_of_class_b` is the same object as `$mock_two_of_class_b`.

How can I mock multiple instances of a class with `PHPUnit`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the `getMock` method creates different instances of mocked class. Take a look on this example:

```
class Foo
{
    protected $value;

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Now we create test for it:

```
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
    public function testFoo()
    {
        $a = $this->getMock('Foo', array('someNonExistingMethod'));
        $b = $this->getMock('Foo', array('someNonExistingMethod'));

        $a->setValue(1);
        $b->setValue(234);

        $this->assertEquals(1, $a->getValue(), 'This test will fail if "a" and "b" objects are the same');
    }
}
```

Pay attention on the second argument in `getMock` method. In that argument you tell `phpunit` which methods will be mocked. If you don't pass any argument at all - then `phpunit` assume you want mock all methods from the object. So, if you pass `array('someNonExistingMethod')` then there won't be any mocked method (and "real" methods will be called on invocations).